# Light source for ionizing air

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, laser

What is a practical and economic way of producing ultra violet light around ionizing frequencies? A tunable light source is preferable in order to adjust the ionization level.

Molecular oxygen ionization energy is according to [Journal of Chemical Education, Vol. 80 No. 12 December 2003 p. 1381](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed080p1381.1) $1.576\times10^{-19}$ Joule per molecule (corresponding to 1260 nanometer wavelength).

This seems like infrared. Does this fit with real observations?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  Please take a moment to complete the Tour so you know how this works:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/Tour